# Prevent text from rotating on the TextPath

Tags: d3.js, svg, text

I'm drawing a roulette with d3.js and I need to prevent rotating of upside down numbers in the fields - so the text labels should stay like cabins on Ferris Wheel - [example](https://prnt.sc/k0oz87)

My fiddle - **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLc59v3y/4/)**

that's the extract to add text

```
     node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", 12)
    .attr("fill", "#ffffff")
    .style("font-size", "10px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#roulette_field_" + i })
    .text(function(d) { return d[0] })
    .attr("startOffset", 9);
```

Is it possible to use textPath element only for anchoring text right to its cell, but not force it to follow the curved line of the field?

If not, how to achieve the right placement in the according cell without rotation?

Also I need to place text in the middle (horizontal) of the cell, but text-anchor middle not working at all, while `startOffset = 9` is going wrong in Internet Explorer;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the texts horizontally positioned, as a regular text, just drop the `<textPath>` and append normal text elements, positioning them with the `centroid` method:

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return roulette.centroid(d, i)[0]
})
.attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return roulette.centroid(d, i)[1]
})
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var nums = [
  ["0", "#2e6632", "50%"],
  ["32", "maroon", "80%"],
  ["15", "#061882", "21%"],
  ["19", "maroon", "30%"],
  ["4", "#061882", "10%"],
  ["21", "maroon", "25%"],
  ["2", "#061882", "99%"],
  ["25", "maroon", "64%"],
  ["17", "#061882", "41%"],
  ["34", "maroon", "18%"],
  ["6", "#061882", "29%"],
  ["27", "maroon", "78%"],
  ["13", "#061882", "69%"],
  ["36", "maroon", "32%"],
  ["11", "#061882", "47%"],
  ["30", "maroon", "88%"],
  ["8", "#061882", "98%"],
  ["23", "maroon", "28%"],
  ["10", "#061882", "5%"],
  ["5", "maroon", "3%"],
  ["24", "#061882", "15%"],
  ["16", "maroon", "33%"],
  ["33", "#061882", "83%"],
  ["1", "maroon", "54%"],
  ["20", "#061882", "14%"],
  ["14", "maroon", "28%"],
  ["31", "#061882", "11%"],
  ["9", "maroon", "74%"],
  ["22", "#061882", "3%"],
  ["18", "maroon", "3%"],
  ["29", "#061882", "23%"],
  ["7", "maroon", "33%"],
  ["28", "#061882", "73%"],
  ["12", "maroon", "83%"],
  ["35", "#061882", "93%"],
  ["3", "maroon", "23%"],
  ["26", "#061882", "13%"]
];

var radius = 104;
var innerRadius = radius - 18;
var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 2);
var canvas2 = d3.select("#canvas2")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 2);

var increase = Math.PI * 2 / nums.length; //length in radians of each slice/field
var half = increase / 2; //half length for offset



var roulette = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(function(d, i) {
    return radius - 18;
  })
  .outerRadius(function(d, i) {
    return 104;
  })
  .startAngle(function(d, i) {
    return (i * increase) - half;
  })
  .endAngle(function(d, i) {
    return (increase * (i + 1)) - half;
  });


var node = canvas.selectAll(".roulette_group")
  .data(nums)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "roulette_group")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "roulette_group_" + i
  })
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");


node.append("path")
  .attr("d", roulette)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d[1];
  });

node.append("text")
  .attr("fill", "#ffffff")
  .style("font-size", "10px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dy", "2px")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return roulette.centroid(d, i)[0]
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return roulette.centroid(d, i)[1]
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d[0]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: PS: Regarding Internet Explorer, good luck trying to make anything work on that...

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you Gerardo. even the bug with IE has vanished with your code.